# Get return type of a function pointer

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, function-pointers, type-traits

suppose I have a pointer to a function that returns int

```
int function() {
    return 10;
}
int main()
{
    int(*mypointer)() = function;
    int value = function();
}
```

I want to implement the same idea for a generic function.
How can I get from any function pointer to the type of
the value the function returns?

I want to achieve this result:

```
int(*mypointer)() = function;
/*type deduced*/ value = mypointer();
```

Comment: If you only need to deduce the type for the `T value = mypointer();` case, then you can probably just use ordinary type inference with `auto`

Comment: Indeed, but what should I write so that the type would actually be deduced, not only in my imagination..

Comment: 'auto' would be nice, but unfortunately I need to build a member class variable with this type, that is why it will not help me.

Comment: what I mean is any variation of std::remove_pointer but will not result in raw function type.

Comment: Can you use `decltype`?

Comment: What you want is surely in [Boost.CallableTraits](https://www.boost.org/libs/callable_traits/), but your question doesn't make much sense to me so I can't be more specific than that